# How to set precision for data in AmCharts Stockcharts

Tags: amcharts

I want to set precision for my data. I know I can do it server side, but what if I wanted to use described in API [Property precision](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/AmChart)? I have a simple example with data here: http://jsfiddle.net/w4Xhp/1/. How to make it round the values to 2 places after the comma?

At the moment I'm trying this with:

```
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
    precision: 2,
    ...
}
```

Btw. This setting seems to work in standard AmChart: http://jsfiddle.net/dYJL2/

Answer (score -1):

Set precision on the value axes.

```
    var valueAxesSettings = new AmCharts.ValueAxesSettings();

    valueAxesSettings.precision = 2;

    chart.valueAxesSettings = valueAxesSettings;
```